# Does there exist such Borel measurable function?

Tags: integration, measure-theory

Does there exist such Borel measurable function $f: \mathbb R \to [0,\infty )$ such that $\int _a ^b f \, dx = \infty$ for all $a< b $?

My feeling is that such function should not exist, but I can't see why. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you considering Lebesgue measure?

Comment: @sinbadh of course